# What does BSCT stand for?

Tags: air-travel, children, terminology

Apparently, BSCT is an acronym for ... baby bassinet. Somehow.

Various airlines use it, for instance:

- [Latam](https://www.latamtrade.com/en_au/procom/bsct)
- [Air China](http://www.airchina.com.cn/en/info/travel-prep/special-traveler/baby04.shtml)

The text only mentions the acronym like

> baby bassinet (BSCT)

without giving any hint on what the letters actually stand for.

**What does BSCT mean exactly?**

Comment: It is not an acronym, simply an abbreviation, but it is better to think of it simply as a code, and codes do not necessarily correspond to what they represent— thus a business class fare might be designated *J*, and Allegiant's IATA code is *G4*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Amadeus](http://api.dev.amadeus.net/api/Development/common/codelist/PNR_SSR.htm) defines it as "Bassinet/Carry cot/Baby basket," so I suppose its origin is "bassinet/cot."